# Confusion in the plane wave solution for the EM wave equation

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations, complex-numbers, plane-wave

When talking about the solution of the Wave Equation for the Electric Field:
\begin{equation}
\ddot{E}=c^2\nabla^2E
\end{equation}
One usually assumes a sinusoidal waveform and writes:
\begin{equation}
E=\mathfrak{R}\{E_0\ e^{i(kx-\omega t)}\}
\end{equation}
Where allegedly the fact that the **real** part is taken is a convention. But it's even more often for me to see it written in the form:
\begin{equation}
E=E_0\sin(kx-\omega t)=\mathfrak{J}\{E_0\ e^{i(kx-\omega t)}\}
\end{equation}
Why do we have this sort of constrast in the definitions? It does seem to me that both are solutions and we can just superpose then to get the general solution, since Maxwell Equations are written in terms of Linear Operators. But I do not understand why sometimes one, or the other is taken to be the solution. What's the difference?

Comment: There is no difference. Any function $f(kx - \omega t)$ could be a solution, whether sinusoidal or not.

Comment: They are equivalent, the general solution will be a linear combination of the two. But maybe there are some boundary condition considerations that lead to these choices in the particular examples you show

Answer (score 0):

They are both solutions to this differential equation. This is a homogenous equation. Any combination of solutions gives me a solution. Whether it be the real part, imaginary part. Or even the complex wave itself. They are all valid solution. Normally people study plane waves due to the implications of monochromatic sources. But in general they do NOT need to be sinusoidal ATALL

The general solution to this equation is

$\vec{F}(\vec{k}\cdot (\vec{r} - ct\hat k))$

Aka, any function translated with a velocity of C